# Finding target coordinates for Manhattan Distance in 8 Puzzle | C++

Tags: c++, math, distance

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the manhattan distance between two 2D array's containing numbers between 0 and 8. Assuming one of the arrays (the goal for the 8 puzzle) is:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  0
```

I understand that between (x<sub>1</sub> , y<sub>1</sub>) & (x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>), the
Manhattan Distance = |x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>| + |y<sub>1</sub> - y<sub>2</sub>|

My code looks something like:

```
for(x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    for(y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        int value = matrix[x][y];
        int targX; //Target X coordinate
        int targY; //Target Y coordinate
        int distX = abs(x - targX);
        int distY = abs(y - targY);
        mDist = mDist + distX + distY;
        }
}
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to get the target coordinates for any particular value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target coordinates for a value `n` are `((n-1) div 3, (n-1) mod 3)`

The above values will be defined assuming the origin `(0,0)` to be at the top left corner, i.e. the square where 1 will be placed. X coordinates increase in the right direction, and Y coordinates in the downward direction.

Comment: I'm sorry can you please explain further? While I see that it works, I don't quite understand how you come to that answer.

Comment: If I understood correctly, for 1 it should return (0, 0) but it returns (0, 1)

Comment: Actually I think, it should be ((n-1) div 3, (n-1) mod 3) for any value n.

Comment: @SpiceTrader: You are correct. I actually wrote this in a hurry, and left for some work. Edited the answer. Hope this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean a two dimensional array. Something like you already have in your code int matrix[3][3]

The question you are asking is not very clear as you are not looking for “manhattan distance between two 2D array”, but rather for a “manhattan distance between two specific elements in the array”. For example, a distance between 2 and 6 in your case will be calculated as follows:

Get the two elements’ 2 dimensional coordinates:

Coordinates of 2: x2=1, y2=0 (x and y coordinates of 2)

Coordinates of 6: x6=2, y6=1 (x and y coordinates of 6)

Get the Manhattan distance:

Manhattan distance = abs(x6 – x2) + abs(y6 – y2);

Substitute: abs(2 – 1) + abs(1 – 0);

Answer: 2